# Tasks based on variable definition

Tags: ansible

I am creating a playbook that takes a variable `ver` at runtime and then runs tasks based on that variable. If that `ver` is defined, it takes the version number and installs a version according to that. If the `ver` is not defined, it defaults to a default version.

My playbook for now looks like:

```
- name: Download Maven from remote repository.
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ baseurl }}/{{ versions[ver] }}"
    dest: /usr/local/
    remote_src: yes
  become: yes
  when: ver is defined

- name: Rename maven folder.
  command: mv /usr/local/apache-maven-{{ver}} /usr/local/maven-{{ver}}
  become: yes
  when: ver is defined

- name: Create symbolic link to maven folder.
  file:
    src: "/usr/local/maven-{{ver}}"
    dest: "/usr/local/maven"
    state: link
  become: yes
  when: ver is defined


- name: Download Default Maven from remote repository.
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ baseurl }}/{{ versions[default_version] }}"
    dest: /usr/local/
    remote_src: yes
    list_files: yes
  become: yes
  when: ver is not defined

- name: Rename maven folder.
  command: mv /usr/local/apache-maven-{{default_version}} /usr/local/maven-{{default_version}}
  become: yes
  when: ver is not defined

- name: Create symbolic link to maven folder.
  file:
    src: "/usr/local/maven-{{default_version}}"
    dest: "/usr/local/maven"
    state: link
  become: yes
  when: ver is not defined
```

As you can see, based on whether a variable is defined or not, I have to write whole new tasks for it.

The above works but I think it's not optimized as I'm writing too much code to get this to work. One idea that I have is to create have `main.yaml` invoke another task file when `ver` is defined and a separate task file when `ver` is not defined.

Is there another way to optimize this? I have many other tasks that deal with version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the filter [*default*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values). For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        version: "{{ ver | default(default_version) }}"
```

If you want to use *default_version* also in case *ver* is empty set the second parameter to *true*

```yaml
        version: "{{ ver | default(default_version, true) }}"
```

See more detail at [*Ansible - Use default if a variable is not defined*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105615/ansible-use-default-if-a-variable-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks. This worked. In this case, I was talking about whether a variable exists or not. But what if there is always a variable but now I need to see whether its value is set to something or if its null. If its null, then default to a `default_value`. Does ansible have any such capability ?

Comment: Ansible doco explains null value variables [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables).